# Java - Error Cannot cast from HashBasedTable<Object,Object,Object> to Table<UUID,PotionEffectType,PotionEffect>

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm having this errors:

1)   Cannot cast from HashBasedTable to Table .

- This is the code in error: In the line:

  ```
   this.restores = **(Table<UUID, PotionEffectType, PotionEffect>)HashBasedTable.create()**;
  ```

2) The method put(UUID, PotionEffectType, PotionEffect) in the type Table is not applicable for the arguments (Object, Object, Object)

- This is the code in error: In the line:

  ```
   this.restores.**put**((Object)player.getUniqueId(), (Object)active.getType(), (Object)active);
  ```

```js
public class MageRestorer implements Listener
{
    private final Table<UUID, PotionEffectType, PotionEffect> restores;
    
    public MageRestorer(final HCF plugin) {
        this.restores = (Table<UUID, PotionEffectType, PotionEffect>)HashBasedTable.create();
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents((Listener)this, (Plugin)plugin);
    }
    
    @EventHandler(ignoreCancelled = true, priority = EventPriority.MONITOR)
    public void onPvpClassUnequip(final PvpClassUnequipEvent event) {
        this.restores.rowKeySet().remove(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
    }
    
    public void setRestoreEffect(final Player player, final PotionEffect effect) {
        boolean shouldCancel = true;
        final Collection<PotionEffect> activeList = (Collection<PotionEffect>)player.getActivePotionEffects();
        for (final PotionEffect active : activeList) {
            if (active.getType().equals((Object)effect.getType())) {
                if (effect.getAmplifier() < active.getAmplifier()) {
                    return;
                }
                if (effect.getAmplifier() == active.getAmplifier() && effect.getDuration() < active.getDuration()) {
                    return;
                }
                this.restores.put((Object)player.getUniqueId(), (Object)active.getType(), (Object)active);
                shouldCancel = false;
            }
        }
        player.addPotionEffect(effect, true);
        if (shouldCancel && effect.getDuration() > 100 && effect.getDuration() < MageClass.DEFAULT_MAX_DURATION) {
            this.restores.remove((Object)player.getUniqueId(), (Object)effect.getType());
        }
    }
    
    @EventHandler(ignoreCancelled = true, priority = EventPriority.MONITOR)
    public void onPotionEffectExpire(final PotionEffectExpiresEvent event) {
        final LivingEntity livingEntity = event.getEntity();
        if (livingEntity instanceof Player) {
            final Player player = (Player)livingEntity;
            final PotionEffect previous = (PotionEffect)this.restores.remove((Object)player.getUniqueId(), (Object)event.getEffect().getType());
            if (previous != null) {
                new BukkitRunnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        player.addPotionEffect(previous, true);
                    }
                }.runTask((Plugin)HCF.getPlugin());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know fix this. This is a clase of bukkit

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, can we see the stack trace? Also, why do you need to cast it? You can store it as a Table; a cast is unnecessary.

For the second error, remove the casts to `Object`. Simply leave them as their actual types. `this.restores.put(player.getUniqueId(), active.getType(), active);`

This should help you get through the issue.